# Int multiplication with long result overflowing

Tags: c, integer, long-integer, integer-overflow

I have some code on an embedded system (the [MSP430FR5994](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367p/slau367p.pdf?ts=1649150529600&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR5969), specifically) that multiplies a number. In this example I am multiplying 80 by 1159, though in my applications voltage_difference_range is usually around 1000.

```
int voltage_difference_range;
long int range_um;

voltage_difference_range = 80;
range_um = voltage_difference_range * 1159;
```

80*1159 = 92720. But, I am displaying 27184 instead. Given that 92720 - 65536 = 27184, I think it's safe to assume this is an overflow issue. The problem is, I don't see why range_um would be overflowing. According to my debugger for MSP430Ware, the value of range_um is the following.

[image]

There seems to me to be 2 more bytes that can contain data, given that I declared it as a long.

Please let me know if more information is needed to solve this issue, or if there is a glaringly obvious solution to this issue.

My full code, in case it helps. Much of the main code is merely initializing the MCU, and the problem code itself is located at one of the flags near the bottom of the code. I have left the initializers in case they help.

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PWM_16HZ 2048
#define PWM_32HZ 1024

char printkeeper;
int memval3_old = 0, memval4_old = 0, memval3_new = 0, memval4_new = 0, i = 0;      //Old is for storing old ADC values
int voltage_difference_new, voltage_difference_old, voltage_difference_range, voltage_difference_doppler; //Remove float whenever possible!
long int range_um, speed_um;
int range, speed;

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;               // Stop WDT

    // GPIO Setup

    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                         // 16Hz Clock Pin Setup

    P1DIR |= BIT0 | BIT1 | BIT2 | BIT5;     // Bits 1.2, 1.5 set to clock (TA1.1, TB0.2) (p88_s, p91_s)
    P1SEL0 |= BIT0 | BIT1 | BIT2 | BIT5;    // See p88-90_s
    PJSEL0 = BIT4 | BIT5;                   // For XT1 Oscillator (p118_s)

    P1SEL1 |= BIT3 | BIT4 ;                 // ADC Pin Setup
    P1SEL0 |= BIT3 | BIT4 ;                 // 1.3 and 1.4 set to ADC input (A3, A4) from p90_s

    P3DIR |= BIT0;                          // Set Pin 3.0 as output, for permanent 3.3V.


    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
    //P1OUT |= BIT0;

    // Clock System Setup

    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                     // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_3;                     // Set DCO to 4MHz (p105)
    CSCTL2 = SELA__LFXTCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;   // Set clock source
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__1 | DIVS__1 | DIVM__1;   // Set all dividers, clock speed 1MHz
    CSCTL4 &= ~LFXTOFF;                     // Something related to the 32kHz oscillator

    do
    {
        CSCTL5 &= ~LFXTOFFG;                // Clear XT1 fault flag
        SFRIFG1 &= ~OFIFG;
    } while (SFRIFG1 & OFIFG);              // Test oscillator fault flag

    CSCTL0_H = 0;                           // Lock clock registers

    //ADC Setup

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12SHT0_0 | ADC12ON;      // Sampling time, S&H=4, ADC12 on [p893, CTL0 = control 0, SHT0_0 = sample & hold time, knowledge of register value from p88_s]

    ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP | ADC12SHS_4 | ADC12CONSEQ_1; // Use TA1.1 to trigger, (SHP means using sample timer (p897), SHS means "sample-and-hold source select" (p895, p84_s)
                                                       // which selects which source is used to activate sampling (4 being TA1.1 because of p84_s), CONSEQ_1 = Conversion sequence select,
                                                       // 1 means multiple-channel which means multiple channels are converted and sampled, memory gets overriden everytime (p881)
    ADC12CTL2 |= ADC12RES_2;                // 12-bit conversion results, p897
    ADC12CTL3 |= ADC12CSTARTADD_3;          // Use MEM3/MCTL3 as first, p898

    ADC12MCTL3 = ADC12INCH_3 ;              // A3 ADC input select from Input Channel 3 (p901), output to MEM3
    ADC12MCTL4 = ADC12INCH_4 | ADC12EOS;    // A4 ADC input select, also setting EOS bit at A4

    ADC12IER0 |= ADC12IE3 | ADC12IE4;      // Enable ADC interrupt [IER = interrupt enable, for IFG0 bit, which tells us when the sequence is complete]


    // Configure TimerA1.1 to periodically trigger ADC12 at a rate of 32Hz
    TA1CCR0 = PWM_32HZ - 1;                   // PWM Period for TA1, 1024/32768 = /32
    TA1CCTL1 = OUTMOD_3;                    // TACCR1 set/reset (Shape of set/reset in p652)

    TA1CCR1 = PWM_32HZ / 2;                   // TACCR1 PWM Duty Cycle
    TA1CTL = TASSEL__ACLK | MC__UP;         // ACLK, up mode

    // Configure TimerA0.0 to generate a 16Hz Square Wave
    TB0CCR0 = PWM_16HZ - 1;                   // PWM Period for TB0, 2048/32768 = /16
    TB0CCTL2 = OUTMOD_7;                    // TBCCR1 set/reset (Shape of set/reset in p652)

    TB0CCR2 = PWM_16HZ /2;                  // TB0CCR2 PWM Duty Cycle
    TB0CTL = TASSEL__ACLK | MC__UP;         // ACLK, up mode

    ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;        // Start sampling/conversion
    printf("135\n");
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits | GIE);     // Enter LPM0, enable interrupts

    __no_operation();

}

// ADC12 interrupt service routine
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=ADC12_B_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12ISR (void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_B_VECTOR))) ADC12ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    switch(__even_in_range(ADC12IV, ADC12IV__ADC12RDYIFG))
    {
        case ADC12IV__ADC12IFG3:            // Vector 18:  ADC12MEM3
            memval3_old = memval3_new;
            memval3_new = ADC12MEM3;
            ADC12IFGR0 &= ~ADC12IFG3;
            break;
        case ADC12IV__ADC12IFG4:            // Vector 20:  ADC12MEM4
            memval4_old = memval4_new;
            memval4_new = ADC12MEM4;

            voltage_difference_new = abs((memval3_new - memval4_new)); // These values are both +ve, rising edge
            voltage_difference_old = abs((memval3_old - memval4_old)); // These values are both +ve, falling edge

            voltage_difference_range = ((voltage_difference_new + voltage_difference_old));
            voltage_difference_doppler = ((voltage_difference_new - voltage_difference_old)); //Lower frequency means moving away
            //printf("%d\n", voltage_difference_range);

            voltage_difference_range = 80;
            range_um = voltage_difference_range * 1159; //Check notebook math, this is in micrometers to avoid floats
            speed_um = voltage_difference_doppler * 15766;  //Check notebook math, also in micrometers

            if (printkeeper == 31){
                printkeeper = 0;
                printf("VD: %d\n", voltage_difference_range);
                printf("R: %d\n", range_um);
                i++;
            }
            else {
                printkeeper = printkeeper + 1;
            }
            ADC12MCTL4 |= ADC12EOS;
            ADC12CTL0 &= ~ADC12ENC;
            ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC;
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `int` values 16 bits?  If so, given that both `voltage_difference_range` and `1159` are `int` values, why would you expect the calculation of `voltage_difference_range * 1159` to be done in anything other than 16 bits?  Assigning the result to a `long` will not change how the calculation is done.

Comment: `range_um = (long int) voltage_difference_range * 1159;` You need to promote one of the argument in expression to higher size.

Comment: `printf("R: %d\n", range_um);` --> `printf("R: %ld\n", range_um);`

Answer (score 1):

The overflow occurs *before* the assignment.  Expressions have *type* and `voltage_difference_range * 1159` is an `int` type expression.

So the overflow occurs and the result is assigned to the `long`, where an *implicit conversion* occurs *after* the overflow.

With respect to expression types: `int * int == int`, but `int * long == long`, so using a literal integer of type `long` will cause the expression to have type `long`:

```
int voltage_difference_range = 80 ;
long range_um = voltage_difference_range * 1159L;
```

In cases where the operands are variables rather then literals you would need a cast of at least one operand if they were both `int` - e.g.:

```
int a = 80 ;
int b = 1159 ;
long x = (long)a * b;
```

Comment: Alternative to `(long)a * b` --> `1L * a * b`.  This avoids narrowing in other cases.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : genius!

Answer (score 0):

`range_um = voltage_difference_range * 1159;` first performs the multiplication, then it assigns the result to `range_um`.

The operands of the multiplication are both `int`, `voltage_difference_range` and `1159`. Multiplication of `int` by `int` is performed in `int` arithmetic, producing an `int` result. Since `int` is 16 bits in your C implementation, multiplying 80 by 1159 overflows the type, and then the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

It appears you are indeed experiencing a wrapping modulo 65,536 in this case, so that the result produced is 27,184 instead of 92,720. Then this result is assigned to `range_um`. The assignment converts the right operand to the type of the left, so 27,184 is converted to `lnog int` and stored in `range_um`. The fact that `range_um` is `long int` has no effect on the prior multiplication.

To perform multiplication with `long int`, change or convert one (or both) of the operands to `long int`, as in `range_um = voltage_difference_range * 1159L;`.